# Buffer line across lon=180 causes banding geopandas matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, shapely, cartopy

I am trying to plot Polygon geometries across the 180 longitude when the map's central_longitude = 180; however there's an artificial banding occurring.

Is there a way to stop matplotlib from banding shown in the red circle?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

lats = np.linspace(-75, 75, 100)
lons = np.linspace(150, 190, 100)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    crs=4326, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(lons, lats)
)
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3174'})
gdf['geometry'] = gdf['geometry'].buffer(90000)
gdf['route'] = 0
gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'EPSG:4326'})

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
ax.add_geometries(gdf['geometry'], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([120, 250, -75, 75], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=[180])
ax.coastlines()
```

Comment: I checked the data with `gdf['geometry'].tail(40)` and it looks strange. I do not know why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reprojecting from `epsg:3174` to `EPSG:4326` jumbles the geometries crossing dateline. You can plot the geodataframe with `epsg:3174` direcly as seen with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

lats = np.linspace(-75, 75, 100)
lons = np.linspace(150, 190, 100)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    crs=4326, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(lons, lats)
)
# gdf2 = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3174'})
gdf2 = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3174)
gdf2['geometry'] = gdf2['geometry'].buffer(90000)
gdf2['route'] = 0

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
ax.add_geometries(gdf2['geometry'], crs=ccrs.epsg(3174))
ax.set_extent([120, 250, -75, 75], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, xlocs=[180])
ax.coastlines()

plt.show()
```

[image: route_xing_dateline]